# Oracle/SQL - a recursive query instead of multiple "union all"?

Tags: sql, oracle, union, recursive-query

I have an existing query, that returns the memberbase 60 days ago (sysdate-60) of my database in one row like this:

```
date -  - - - members
sysdate-60   200.000
```

I want to combine the results of multiple queries of this one in one query in order to get a result like this:

```
date - - - -  members
sysdate-60   200.000
sysdate-59   210.000
sysdate-58   220.000
```

I can do it by editing manually the date of every single query and use "UNION ALL", but this is annoying. I'm looking for a better solution.

I stumbled across "recursive queries" and thought this could solve my problem but I wasn't able to customise it for my needs. Can you?

Looking foward to your answers.

EDIT:

let's assume that this is the query I use and that there is no other way to retrieve the amount of members:<

```
SELECT sysdate-60 AS date, count(*) AS members FROM members WHERE start_date<sysdate-60 AND end_date>=sysdate-60
```

Comment: it's kind of difficult to guess the names of the fields/tables in your db. Please post the query you're currently using.

Comment: Do you have a **single** record for **every** date?

Comment: A recursive query is probbaly not the right answer. Can you post the structure of the members table(s) and your existing query?

Comment: SELECT sysdate-l, count(*) FROM members , ( select level l from dual connect by level <= 60) WHERE start_date<sysdate-l AND end_date>=sysdate-l group by l

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query to generate numbers from 1 to 60:

```
select level  from dual connect by level <= 60;
```

and then join it with your existing query e.g.

```
select  'sysdate('|| d|| ')' 
      , sum( case round(sysdate - created) when d then 1 else 0 end)
  from 
        user_objects
      , ( select level d from dual connect by level <= 60)
group by d      
order by 1
;
```

or

```
 SELECT sysdate - d, count(*) 
 FROM members 
   , ( select level d from dual connect by level <= 60) 
 WHERE start_date<sysdate-d 
   AND end_date>=sysdate-d 
 group by d
;
```

Comment: I know, but how does this help me?

Comment: you can join it with your existing query

Comment: @user2675284 i have append an example with your query to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this; you just need a counter.

This query will give you a list of the past 60 days, ending with the current date:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL + 1 AS TheDate
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 60
```

If the list should end with yesterday's date, just remove the `+ 1` from the example.

You can then join this into your main query and you'll be able to get rid of all those `UNION` queries.